# Number of strings that contain a subset of symbols

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider an alphabet $\Sigma$ where $|\Sigma|=n$ and a subset $S\subseteq\Sigma$ with $|S|=m$. How many strings of length $k$ (possilby greater than $n$) are there that contain all the symbols in $S$?

Comment: k must be at least n just to have at least 1. if repetitions aren't allowed then k=n. only if repetitions are allowed is k>n true.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee For $k<m$ the answer is trivial, 0. Repetition is allowed.

Comment: and for k=n ? ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee For $k=m$ it is $m!$. For larger values (including $n$), I do not know.

Comment: Hint: Inclusion-exclusion

Comment: m could equal n based on your notation. I'll admit I did confuse them.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the hint. I don't seem to be able to formulate it properly though. I get into a recursive mess.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $A$ be all words of length $k$, and, for each $i\in S$,  let $A_i$ be all words of length $k$ which do not contain $i$.

Then you want to calculuate: $$\left|A\setminus\bigcup_{i\in S} A_i\right|$$

Then you use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: The problem that I have is that $A_i$ are not mutually exclusive so I am subtracting some words more than once.

Comment: That is the point of inclusion-exclusion

Comment: @igor Inclusion-exclusion handles that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think I was expecting a "closed form" solution for it without knowing what it actually meant. Inclusion-exclusion is the way to go.

Comment: There is a formula with sigma notation.